# Python Binary Multiplication. Divide and Conquer

Tags: python, binary, multiplication, divide-and-conquer

I need to understand why my code gives wrong answers. The task is to create binary multiplication by divide and conquer method. I found some papers that describe this type of problem: 
[wikibooks algorithms](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithms/Divide_and_Conquer#Divide_and_Conquer_Multiplication)
[UTSC paper (page 4)](http://www.utsc.utoronto.ca/~bretscher/b36/f13/lectures/w4.pdf)

Here is my Python code (3.5.2)

```
def add(A, B):
    a_str = "".join([str(a) for a in A])
    b_str = "".join([str(b) for b in B])

    bin_a = int(a_str, 2)
    bin_b = int(b_str, 2)

    return [int(a) for a in str(bin(bin_a + bin_b))[2:]]


def add_n(*args):
    if len(args) <= 1:
        return args[0]

    bin_sum = [0]
    for num in args:
        bin_sum = add(bin_sum, num)

    return bin_sum


def shift(A, n):
    if n <= 0:
        return A

    a_str = "".join([str(a) for a in A])

    bin_a = int(a_str, 2)
    bin_a = bin(bin_a << n)
    return [int(a) for a in str(bin_a)[2:]]


def lfill(A, n):
    return [0] * (n - len(A)) + A


def multiply(A, B):
    n = len(A)
    half = n // 2

    if n <= 1:
        return [A[0] * B[0]]

    xl, xh = A[:half], A[half:]
    yl, yh = B[:half], B[half:]

    a = multiply(xh, yh)
    b = multiply(xh, yl)
    c = multiply(xl, yh)
    d = multiply(xl, yl)

    b = add(b, c)
    a = shift(a, n)
    b = shift(b, half)

    return add_n(a, b, d)
```

The problematic test 1:

```
A = [1, 1, 1, 1]
B = [0, 1, 0, 0]
result: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
real result: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

The problematic test 2:

```
A = [1, 1, 1, 1]
B = [0, 0, 0, 1]
result: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
real result: [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Value trace for test 2:

```
              n half
Before Shift [2, 1]: a: [1] b:[1]
After Shift:         a: [1, 0, 0] b:[1, 0]
Before Shift [2, 1]: a: [0] b:[0]
After Shift:         a: [0] b:[0]
Before Shift [2, 1]: a: [1] b:[1]
After Shift:         a: [1, 0, 0] b:[1, 0]
Before Shift [2, 1]: a: [0] b:[0]
After Shift:         a: [0] b:[0]
Before Shift [4, 2]: a: [1, 1, 0] b:[1, 1, 0]
After Shift:         a: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] b:[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

So, as you can see the problem is in the count of zero's, but from case to case it's different. This code doesn't work for all binaries which are unpaired length, but it's not a problem because it could be easily normalized.

Comment: What have you done to diagnose the problem?  I don't see any attempt to check which intermediate values might be incorrect, or to trace the execution flow.

Comment: Added, trace for Test 2. Actually, because this algorithm is recursive it has a lot of different values. I was using Debug but seems like the problem is in the algorithm itself.

Comment: As I assume this to be homework, I will not give you the solution but I'll give you this pointer: Consider MSB/LSB. Which bits are which?

Comment: Wow, I found the mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Correct multiply function:

```
def multiply(A, B):
n = len(A)
half = n // 2

if n <= 1:
    return [A[0] * B[0]]

xl, xh = A[:half], A[half:]
yl, yh = B[:half], B[half:]

a = multiply(xh, yh)
b = multiply(xh, yl)
c = multiply(xl, yh)
d = multiply(xl, yl)

b = add(b, c)

d = shift(d, n)
b = shift(b, half)

return add_n(a, b, d)
```

Comment: I haven't checked your solution but I imagine it generates the correct result, however, it has very strange variable names, as `xl` and `yl` contains the high bits and `xh` and `yh` contains the low bits. I think a better solution would be to just change (in the original implementation) 'xl, xh = A[:half], A[half:]` to `xh, xl = A[:half], A[half:]` and the same for `yl, yh` and `B`. I.e., I have just reversed `xl` and `xh`.